# jQuery AJAX is being interrupted without error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on the following code using PHPStorm. I have three files:
* `loginForm.php` (the html/php/javascript for logging in)
* `firstlogin.php` (php code that send variables to public function)
* `user.php` (The public function for checking the DB)

When the form is submitted, the page I am on reloads and that is it. Nothing changes.

Looking at the network tab in the inspector I see that the page calls `firstlogin.php` the way it should. But it stops processing immediately and the debugger tab pops up because the processing was paused do to an error. It highlights line 3454 in `jquery-3.3.1.min.js: s.send(t.hasContent && t.data || null)`. Upon continuing the code, nothing is returned, no headers or content. The browser just says **"An error occurred trying to load the resource"**. If I click on the `firstlogin.php` to view the content/headers/cookies/etc. Clicking on the reloaded `loginform.php` gives me a 200 OK. I will include pictures and the code below. I don't know what to do.

I have tried:
- Changing the form to onsubmit(run the function)

- Change submit input to button
- Change the submit button to onclick(run the function)
- Make jquery listen for click of the button
- Make jquery listen for submit of the form (Current)
- ----Obviously these didn't really change anything but I had to try.
- Change data type to JSON & serialize the form

I also tried advice from this page:
[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797169/jquery-ajax-issue)

```js
<!--loginform.php Javascript-->

$(function() {
  $("#login-form").submit(function() {
    if ($("#password").val() !== "") {
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?=CALL_LOGINFILE?>",
        data: {
          password: $("#password").val()
        },
      }).done(function(msg) {
        if (msg !== "") {
          alert(msg);
        } else {
          window.location = "<?=CALL_REGISTER?>";
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("Please fill all fields with valid data!");
    }
  });
});


<!--firstlogin.php Javascript-->

<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/Components/Classes/user.php';
    require __DIR__ . '/CallMeFirst.php';
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_DEFAULT);
    if( $user->loginPW($password) ) {
        die;
    } else {
        $user->printMsg();
        die;
    }
    ?>


<!--user.php Javascript-->

<?php
    public function loginPW($password){
        if(is_null($this->pdo)){
            $this->msg = 'Connection did not work out!';
            return false;
        } else {
            $pdo = $this->pdo;
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE id = 1 limit 1');
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->fetch();
            if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
                    $this->user = $user;
                    session_regenerate_id();
                    $_SESSION['user']['id'] = $user['id'];
                    return true;
            } else {
                $this->msg = 'Invalid login information';
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

```html
<!--loginform.php HTML-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.cookie@1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<form id="login-form" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row text-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <input type="button" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="2" class="btn btn-login" value="SUBMIT">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

header tab for firstlogin.php

[image: header tab for firstlogin.php]

header tab for reloaded login form.php

[image: header tab for reloaded login form.php]

debugger tab

[image: debugger tab]

Comment: Sounds like you've set your debugger to break on exceptions, even caught ones. I wouldn't recommend that, especially when working with large libraries like jQuery

Comment: Yes, because I was looking for Anything that would return an error, before that I had nothing. I thought maybe it would find something useful.

Comment: I'd turn off the auto-breakpoints, at least until you can sort out the source of this particular error.

Comment: Is the url you are POSTing to on a different origin? Have you tried to cURL the url with some data to see what that does?

Comment: Do you mean a different domain? No. ‘Filelogin.php’ is up one directory of ‘loginform.php’. I use absolute paths to call it, not relative. But I have tried relative too. I setup a curl and it seems to work. It responds if the password is invalid, which the AJAX doesn’t do.

Comment: *** I should mention that this code worked fine before it broke. I’m not sure what happened exactly, but it just stopped working for no apparent reason.

Comment: Yes I meant different domain, in case it was a cross-origin issue. Given what you say about the code previously working then breaking for no reason (and also because cURL works): I'd actually be looking for small syntax errors in other areas of the Javascript code (I'm assuming you've simplified/isolated your code above). If you're tracking with git, can you trace back to where the code worked?

Comment: Maybe you could boil down your example. Looking at your code, it looks like you could set up a new .html file with a simple boilerplate, include jQuery, run your AJAX call with javascript inline & hard-code the values of the PHP constants, and hard-code the password data. If that AJAX call responds then you'll know if your code above is working and if you should actually be looking elsewhere. I quickly copied your AJAX call and there doesn't seem to be any issue with it in principal, so maybe your server/browser is doing something unusual (to which end, have you tried a different browser?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the the form was submitting and interrupting the AJAX request. I discovered this because when the ajax function was initiated by `$("#login-submit").click(function() {` the page would function normally if the button was clicked (if the button input type was set to `type=button`). But when I would press enter (when the button input type was set to `type=submit`), it would perform the error. By changing the JS to `$("#login-form").submit(function() {` the error would occur if I clicked the button or pressed enter.

I FIXED this by adding the jQuery `event.preventDefault();` to the JS as follows:

```
$("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     //rest of code here
 }
```

This stops the form from submitting when the enter key is pressed or the button is clicked. This allows the AJAX request to process without interruption.